# How to validate XML when schema is referenced in the XML document?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema

The XML contains a link to the schema. How can I get C# to validate the XML against the schema?

```
<Specification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schemas.company.com/Specification.xsd">
    <FirstElement>...</FirstElement>
</Specification>
```

I've changed the schema location URL for this post, so this example won't actually work. I've tried the following:

```
var schemaErrors = new List<string>();
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore,
    ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings,
    ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
};
settings.ValidationEventHandler += (o, e) => { schemaErrors.Add(e.Message); };

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlText, settings))
{
    XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
    var actual = schemaErrors;

    Assert.That(actual, Is.Empty);
}
```

where xmlText is the XML from above.

I get the following errors:

"Cannot load the schema for the namespace '' - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
"Could not find schema information for the element 'Specification'."

I've searched the internet for answers but it seems everyone uses a local schema.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear there's nothing wrong with the code. Despite the schema validating correctly in XmlSpy, the unit test was failing.

The hint was in the error message "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.". Once I asked the host to enable logging the problem went away. Most odd.